# Get Front End Properties of Attribute

Tags: attributes, frontend

i would like to know how to get the frond end properties in magento because in the resource model that i got these properties are not available, i dont know why or how to get them, this is the collection that i got:

```
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection');
```

but if i try to get any front end property doesnot give anything:

```
  foreach($collection as $attribute){         
        Mage::log($attribute->getIsSearchable(),null,"layerfilter.log");
   }
```

Output: 
     2014-06-23T21:44:48+00:00 DEBUG (7):

Comment: Try `$collection = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection();` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting collection of all attributes, you should load each attribute individually by its attribute code then it will give you the front-end properties of respective attribute

```
<pre>
$attribute_code = "manufacturer"; 
$attribute_details = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("catalog_product", $attribute_code); 
$options = $attribute_details->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
echo $attribute_details->getIsSearchable(); 
</pre>
```

here we loaded 'manufacturer' attribute by passing its code. Here, It is returning its options and print 1 or 0 by `getIsSearchable() .`

Answer (score 1):

I assume, this is what you need:

```
$attribute_code = "name"; 
$attribute_details =
Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute('catalog_product',    $attribute_code);
$attribute = $attribute_details->getData();
print_r($attribute);
```